# avoid duplicate model instance in django without any django unique constraint error

Tags: django

I write a news aggregator service and I run a periodic task for every 5 minutes to fetch top stories based on votes and save data to the database.
everything working fine but I run into a problem.
in every 5mint there may or may not a new entry and my service save the duplicate entry to DB.
if I use `unique=True` then my celery worker show error regarding django unique constraint violation and crashes.

is there any way to avoid duplicate data without error.

i know maybe its not a best practise but i have this use case.
please suggest how to do this in django.

model.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=100)
    upvotes = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500,null=True)
    sentiment = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Article"
        verbose_name_plural = "Articles"
        unique_together =  (("title", "url"),)
```

tasks.py

```
@periodic_task(
    run_every=(crontab(minute='*/5')),
    name="add",
    ignore_result=False
)
def add():
    response = requests.get(TOP_STORIES, headers=headers)
    for i in response.json()[:10]:
        response_id = requests.get(
            "some_url".format(id=str(i)),
            headers=headers)
        item = response_id.json()
        params = {
            "txt": item.get("title")
        }
        response_senti = requests.post(
            "https://community-sentiment.p.mashape.com/text/", headers=headers_sent, data=params
        )

        senti = response_senti.json().get("result")

        Article.objects.create(username=item.get("by"),
                               title=item.get("title"),
                               url=item.get("url"),
                               upvotes=item.get("score"),
                               sentiment=senti.get("sentiment")
                               )
```

Comment: Question without code will most likely be closed. Please include some sample code, narrow your problem so people could help you quickly.

Comment: You can use update_or_create function to archive that https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create